# best practice data design in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, database

How could i structure data for following scenario?

There is an app called Food Ordering System. It contains

**Username(Who is registering this restaurant menus for online order)**

**Restaurant_name**

**Description**

**Location**

**Estimated Delivery**

**Menu(Has multiple menus for one restaurant)**

**My design**

```
  "restaurant":{
    "username":{
        "restaurant_name":"KFC Restaurant",
        "description":"short description on restaurant",
        "estimated delivery":"1hour/km",
        "distance":"20km away",
        "location":"Kathmandu",
        "rating":"rating star up to 5",
        "menus":{
            "menu":{
                "item":"buff momo",
                "price":"$5",
                "rating":"rating star up to 5"
                },
            "menu":{
                "item":"Fried Chicken",
                "price":"$10",
                "rating":"rating star up to 5"
            },
            "menu":{
                "item":"BBQ",
                "price":"$20",
                "rating":"rating star up to 5"
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is my design the best practice design?

Comment: There is no best practice because it all depends on what you plan to do with this data and how complicated it will get (for example a user with 1000 menu's). So it would help if you can also tell what you are planning to do instead of only showing what data you have.

Comment: I am trying to create food ordering system where each user can register their restaurant or hotel menus and user will order their preferred menu. There wont be more than 2000 data and menus for one restaurant wont be more than 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on what you want to do with this data.

If in your website you want to show a list of all restaurant and when you click on restaurant show the list of menu they are offering, storing the menu inside the restaurant might not be a good idea.

Because according to the doc :

> When we read a data node in our Firebase database, we also retrieve all of its children!

(the old one) https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data

Also, imagine if you want to do a search bar and look for a menu (like chicken nuggets) and return the list of restaurant offering this I would design your database this way:

```
"restaurant":{
"$username":{
    "restaurant_name":"KFC Restaurant",
    "description":"short description on restaurant",
    "estimated delivery":"1hour/km",
    "distance":"20km away",
    "location":"Kathmandu",
    "rating":"rating star up to 5",
    ...
  }
}

"menus":{
  "$username" : {
        "menu":{
            "item":"buff momo",
            "price":"$5",
            "rating":"rating star up to 5"
            },
        "menu":{
            "item":"Fried Chicken",
            "price":"$10",
            "rating":"rating star up to 5"
        },
        "menu":{
            "item":"BBQ",
            "price":"$20",
            "rating":"rating star up to 5"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what exactly i am trying to implement. I was confuse with the menu part now i am clear. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `$username` key?

Comment: Ahh I got it, `Username(Who is registering this restaurant menus for online order)`