# Ordering and filtering denormalized data with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase to build an application that has two models, `A` and `B`:

- There is a one to many relationship between `A` and `B` (`A` has many `B`).
- `A` and `B` need to be somewhere easy to query, so I need a way to fetch all `A` models that have a property that fulfills a condition. Same with `B`.
- `B` has a property `createdAt` (that never changes) and a property `status` (that changes every now and then) and I want to list all `Bs` that are owned by a particular `A` and which `status` and/or `createdAt` properties fulfill some condition.
- `Bs` are private and can only be read by a user that is authenticated and can read the `A` to which they belong (User can read `b1` if can read `a1` and `a1` belongs to `b1`).

Following [Firebase guidelines](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), my first try was to do something like this:

```
"As": {
  "a1": {
    ...
    Bs: {
      "b1": true,
      ...
    },
  },
  ...
},
"Bs": {
  "b1": {
    ...,
    "status": "OPEN",
    "createdAt": 1464249410579,
  },
  ...
},
```

The problem with this solution is that to access `Bs` that belong to `a1` which status is `OPEN` and are not older than one month, I have to access `a1.Bs`, get all the id's and then access `Bs` one by one (which is fine, according to [Firebase guidelines](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)) and then filter them to find out if they fulfill my condition, which I find extremely inefficient.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: It depends on how you want to access the data, but putting it all under `As` will solve the issue you are describing

Comment: When you say `A` has many `B`. does a `b` can be link to many `a`? I mean `a1` and `a2` can both have `b1`?

Comment: @eikooc the problem with this is that it would make `B` difficult to search.

Comment: @Crema no. It's a one to many relationship and not a many to many one.

Comment: Just duplicate the data. That is the what people usually do with NoSQL databases

Comment: @eikooc duplicate the data, how?

Comment: @AlejandroPérez whenever you save the data save it to both `As` and `Bs` or have a server running that pulls out every new `b` from the `As`

Comment: Question for clarification: You started:  *query B... that are owned by a particular A and which status and/or createdAt properties fulfill some condition.*  So you want to query node 'b' by three different parameters; 1) belongs to an 'a' node  2) status = open/closed and 3) createdAt = some creation date. That would conceptually be a single query testing three parameters simultaneously. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jay that is correct. Don't forget point 4, though.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear at the beginning, but B models are much bigger than `status` and `createdAt`. Those two properties are the ones are susceptible of being required when ordering/filter a query.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking a bit, we came up with this solution:

```
"As": {
  "a1": {
    ...
    Bs: {
      "b1": { "status": "OPEN", "createdAt": 1464249410579 },
      ...
    },
  },
  ...
},
"Bs": {
  "b1": {
    ...,
    "status": "OPEN",
    "createdAt": 1464249410579,
  },
  ...
},
```

This solution allows us to keep the structure of the database flat, so that data `As` and `Bs` are searchable and listable by, for example, an admin user. It also tries to minimize data duplication, and it would work for as many properties as we would like to include in the query.

To fetch `Bs` that belong to `A`:

```
ref.child('as/:aId/bs').once('value')
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(...) // Access /bs/:bId where :bId = snapshotItem.key()
```

To fetch `Bs` that belong to `A` and `status` is `OPEN`:

```
ref.child('as/:aId/bs')
  .orderByChild('status')
  .equalTo('OPEN')  
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(...) // Access /bs/:bId where :bId = snapshotItem.key()
```

To fetch `Bs` that belong to `A` and `status` is `OPEN` and `createdAt` fulfills condition:

```
ref.child('as/:aId/bs')
  .orderByChild('status')
  .equalTo('OPEN')  
  .once('value')
  .then(filterBsThatDontFulFillCreatedAtCondition)
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(...) // Access /bs/:bId where :bId = snapshotItem.key()
```

In this last case we have to do some filtering in the client, but this is due to Firebase limitations, and I don't think we could avoid it. In any case, this is done on an array of id's, and not on the model itself, which might have 20 or 30 properties, so we are avoiding to bring the full models that we won't need.

Comment: Well, if filtering on the client is ok, then the whole thing is super easy. If your client is iOS, query for the B's that belong to A and stuff them into an array. Then you can filter that array where open = true and createdAt = 12345. All of about 10 lines of code. I'm sure there's a filter method on other platforms as well.

Comment: Oh, and for determining which user can read the nodes, a Rule that defines the user must be auth'd and that their user_id exists in the A node and the B node they are trying to read; just add a /user/uid_0:true, uid_1: true etc.

Comment: @Jay, to your first comment: yes, that's exactly the solution I'm proposing in my answer. The "tricky" part is that `status` and `createdAt` must be in `a1.Bs` so that you can filter the array before bringing the whole array with full objects to the client, which would be expensive.

Comment: @Jay, to your second comment: thanks a lot, that's exactly what we are doing at the moment. I added that constraint in my question because then otherwise there would be no need for nesting, you could just query `/offers` with certain parameters and that's all. For security reasons `/offers` is not accessible by a regular user (maybe readable by an admin).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

```
 "As": {
  "a1": {
    ...
  },
  ...
},
"Bs": {
  "a1" : {
      "b1": {
        "status": "OPEN",
        "createdAt": 1464249410579,
      },
  },
},
```

Where `a1` is the key of you `A`

This way you can query easily all the `bs` that belongs to a `a`

This is what I advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345365/best-practice-data-design-in-firebase/37346670#37346670)

Comment: You actually meant to use `{ "status": "OPEN", "createdAt": 1464249410579 }` instead of `true` when you make the relationship in `a1.Bs`, right? I think the example is confusing.

Comment: No I mean remove all the `bs` from your model `A`. And in your model `B` store all the `bs` under the `a` they belong to. So instead of querying on `firebaseUrl/Bs/` query on `firebaseurl/Bs/${aKey}/`

Comment: The problem about this solution is that `B` would be difficult to search (fetch all `B's` which status is `OPEN`)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a crack at this.

```
As
  a1
    Bs
      b1: true
      b2: true
  a2
    Bs
      b2: true
Bs
  b1:
    "open_a1": 1464249410579
  b2:
    "open_a1": 1464249410590
    "open_a2": 1464249410595
```

This structure allows your code to know, from the As node all of the Bs linked to a1

You can query Bs for all open_a1 < one month

```
ref.queryByChild("open_a1").queryStaringAtValue(today)
                           .queryEndingAtValue(one month from today)
```

This is totally untested so I may need to modify the solution a tad.

Comment: I think it's cumbersome to use the status as an id, given that it's going to change every now and then and you have to update it.